# Display a small image of a page by using its URL

Tags: jquery, image, url

I am looking for a way to get a small image of a web page by giving its URL as an argument.
I would like it appears like when you use gchat and you send a youtube url.
Is there any Jquery plugin who can do that ? (I am not using wordpress)

Thank you !

Comment: Maybe you can use a service like [thumbalizr](http://www.thumbalizr.com/)?

Comment: qTip + websnapr.com ? http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip/demos/content/thumbnail

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do this only with javascript. Ajax (the way to load external content in our pages) can't access to pages of other domains.

Yo need to create a server programed service (PHP, ASP, C, Phyton,...) . This service must load this url and get the images. Then you can load this service with ajax as Json or XML.

This is same that you can find in facebook, pinterest, etc.

Comment: Is there any already existing such service implemented in PHP ?

Comment: In PHP you can do a very simple script:

<?
$myHtml = file_get_contents( $_GET['url'] );
$re_extractImages = '/<img.*src=["\']([^ ^"^\']*)["\']/ims';
preg_match_all( $re_extractImages  , $myHtml , $matches );
$imagesInMyHtml = $matches[1];
echo json_encode($imagesInMyHtml);
?>


With Jquery you can load this script in json with native $.get()